# Publishing Page Goes back to "Checked Out" Status after Publish

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, publishing-page, versioning, check-out, check-in

I have an odd issue where a page on one of our subsites remains checked out by the site admin. When I go in to "Override Check-Out", the action goes through, and then when I publish the page, it appears to go through, but then after the page gets refreshed, the page goes right back to being checked out.

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Are there any workflows associated on this list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a web part page and a couple of the associated web parts were checked out.